# Will HR team cross verify the offer letter before giving counter offer?

Tags: job-offer, new-job

I have resigned from my current organisation as I got a good offer. My manager promised to give me level raise and a counter offer for which he asked me to show the offer letter so that he could discuss with HR team for same. I forwarded him my offer letter and the email that i received from my new organisation. Now, Will the HR team cross check or contact my new organisation to check the authentication of the offer letter? If it happens, will it harm my new job offer in any way?

Comment: This is a very dangerous game you are playing.  That offer was confidential information, and the new company probably will not be happy you shared it with your current employer.  If they do call to verify the offer, you will not be very trusted at the new organization.  In my opinion, you made a serious tactical error.

Comment: Did you actually resign already? Or just give notice.

Comment: I wouldn't have forwarded that letter. If they didn't believe you, that was their problem, not yours. See this related (but different) discussion http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/64958/can-one-company-ask-offer-letter-of-another-company

Comment: Post your questions here _before_ you act. Worst case, your old company says "bye, bye, Jack", and the new company says "you showed our confidential offer letter to someone else, find a job elsewhere".

Comment: [Don't accept a counter offer.](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/54748/when-does-accepting-an-offer-to-stay-with-my-current-firm-make-sense/54752#54752). Accept the offer from the company that's willing to pay you what you are worth and don't play games with offer letters.

Comment: @Brandin 'Resign' and 'give notice' are the same thing.

Comment: Why is it confidential information if somebody offers me a job? Is this another Europe/US difference?

Comment: Of course it is confidential. It means "company X is hiring people". That's information that a competitor might want to know. It also seems to say "company X is offering $Y for this position", which is more confidential information.

Comment: Best answer would be "that's okay, I'm leaving and not interested in a counter-offer."  If it takes you leaving for them to consider paying you what you are actually worth, you'd be stupid to accept a counter-offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think they will check, and if they do, that is not a real problem, you are free to resign from a position while explaining you have a better offer, then the company might give you a counter offer, I don't see any problem here.

If it happens, which I doubt, from the point of view of the other company, that will add to your value, you will be seen as someone who is enough valuable to do efforts to keep it.

The only bad side may be that the new company might see the leak of the offer as a intent from your part to play a double game, which would be problematic for you. They will think you are not trustworthy. It really depends of your country.

Accepting the counter offer is also really dangerous. Because it will put you in a strange position with your colleagues and your hierarchy, adding to the fact that they will think about you as "the guy who is living for money".

In your position, that is a game I would have not played.

Comment: Leaking their offer just means that you cannot be trusted with any confidential information. Which is a very, very bad thing.

Comment: @gnasher729 depend of the country, the hierarchy and how people see it in the company. For example, in my country, it is not really a problem, it is considered being honest to inform your previous company about an offer, except if you signed it, of course. I can understand the problem of trust anyway.

Comment: "the guy who is living for money". Without money I don't think many people would work. Nothing wrong in getting as much as possible.

Comment: I say, if you were happy at your job you would never have been looking at other jobs, a counter offer'd job will never make you happy.
Also if you were worth the counter offer to begin with, why did they not make that offer to you before you decided to leave?

Answer (score 0):

It's highly unprofessional to ask the HR for the offer letter. It's worse you send it to them. And it's worst if they call the company to check its correctness.

I can almost guarantee that that's not gonna happen though: I can't even imagine they pick up the phone and ask "Hey, would you confirm you are actually offering this, so we will continue bargaining with him over this?"

For future, you don't even need to mention about the other offer.