# Is it okay to share details some details of an in hand offer to another potential employer?

Tags: job-offer, internship

I interviewed for a company (say A) a few days ago from whom I received an offer letter today. I got another offer from another company (B) 2 days ago (after interviewing with company A). The offer from company B is much better than the offer from company A but now company A is asking me about the details of the offer from company B like the name of company B, terms of the offer like the CTC offered by company B, the tenure of internship and whether they are going to convert the internship to a job. I have given them these details over a telephonic conversation.

Is sharing details about another offer such as the pay and the tenure of internship legal or will it land me in some trouble?

They are asking me to share the offer letter as well to which I was a little uncomfortable and will politely deny sharing the offer letter.

Comment: I doubt this is illegal but it's highly unprofessional in my opinion.  It will reflect badly on you and that is rarely, if ever, a good thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can one company ask offer letter of another company](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/64958/can-one-company-ask-offer-letter-of-another-company)

Comment: So sunce the interview with A was prior to B, how does A know? If I was A and you told me I would be worried about your trustworthiness especially if B asked you to keep quiet or expected you to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can share the general outline.

But no, you were correct not to share the name of company B, nor the offer letter itself.

This is what can happen when you share the name of company B:

[What can I do if one employer used offer letter from first company against me?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/148389/what-can-i-do-if-one-employer-used-offer-letter-from-first-company-against-me)